# How to pan and zoom video in OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, rtsp, ip-camera

I am trying to implement pan and zoom functions in my RTSP camera stream using Python. I want to be able to use my mouse wheel to zoom in and out from the video and click and drag to move the video around. However, I have not been able to find any tutorials on handling these mouse events in OpenCV.

Is there such a way or will I have resort to using keystrokes to pan and zoom my video?

Comment: with ```imshow``` you already have it

Comment: I understand `imshow` is used to output the video frames in a window, but how can I move the video around with my mouse?

Comment: By dragging and sliding mouse cursor on the window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use mouse event and imshow to achieve this function.

```
def mouse_event_callback(self, event,x,y,flags,param):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEWHEEL:

...
cv2.namedWindow('Test')
cv2.setMouseCallback('Test',self.mouse_event_callback)
while True:
     cv2.imshow('Test',img)
```

Comment: This was what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is deciding the scale changed every time on mouse wheel. After you get the current scale (v.s. origin image) and correct region of image you want to show on screen, you can get the position and length of rectangle on scaled image. So you can draw this rectangle on scaled image.

In my [github](https://github.com/DennisLiu1993/Fastest_Image_Pattern_Matching)，checking OnMouseWheel () and RefreshSrcView () in Fastest_Image_Pattern_Matching/ELCVMatchTool/ELCVMatchToolDlg.cpp may give what you want.

Although it's c++ code, but only imshow () and resize () are used. Focusing on how I change the scale and how the new rectangle to be draw in scaled image will be enough.

Effect:
[image]
[image]

Part of the code:

```
BOOL CELCVMatchToolDlg::OnMouseWheel (UINT nFlags, short zDelta, CPoint pt)
{
    POINT pointCursor;
    GetCursorPos (&pointCursor);
    ScreenToClient (&pointCursor);
    // TODO: 在此加入您的訊息處理常式程式碼和 (或) 呼叫預設值
    if (zDelta > 0)
    {
        if (m_iScaleTimes == MAX_SCALE_TIMES)
            return TRUE;
        else
            m_iScaleTimes++;
    }
    if (zDelta < 0)
    {
        if (m_iScaleTimes == MIN_SCALE_TIMES)
            return TRUE;
        else
            m_iScaleTimes--;
    }
    CRect rect;
    //GetWindowRect (rect);
    GetDlgItem (IDC_STATIC_SRC_VIEW)->GetWindowRect (rect);//重要

    if (m_iScaleTimes == 0)
        g_dCompensationX = g_dCompensationY = 0;

    int iMouseOffsetX = pt.x - (rect.left + 1);
    int iMouseOffsetY = pt.y - (rect.top + 1);

    double dPixelX = (m_hScrollBar.GetScrollPos () + iMouseOffsetX + g_dCompensationX) / m_dNewScale;
    double dPixelY = (m_vScrollBar.GetScrollPos () + iMouseOffsetY + g_dCompensationY) / m_dNewScale;


    m_dNewScale = m_dSrcScale * pow (SCALE_RATIO, m_iScaleTimes);

    if (m_iScaleTimes != 0)
    {
        int iWidth = m_matSrc.cols;
        int iHeight = m_matSrc.rows;

        
        m_hScrollBar.SetScrollRange (0, int (m_dNewScale * iWidth - m_dSrcScale * iWidth) - 1 + BAR_SIZE);
        m_vScrollBar.SetScrollRange (0, int (m_dNewScale * iHeight - m_dSrcScale * iHeight) - 1 + BAR_SIZE);
        int iBarPosX = int (dPixelX * m_dNewScale - iMouseOffsetX + 0.5);
        m_hScrollBar.SetScrollPos (iBarPosX);
        m_hScrollBar.ShowWindow (SW_SHOW);
        g_dCompensationX = -iBarPosX + (dPixelX * m_dNewScale - iMouseOffsetX);

        int iBarPosY = int (dPixelY * m_dNewScale - iMouseOffsetY + 0.5);
        m_vScrollBar.SetScrollPos (iBarPosY);
        m_vScrollBar.ShowWindow (SW_SHOW);
        g_dCompensationY = -iBarPosY + (dPixelY * m_dNewScale - iMouseOffsetY);

        //滑塊大小
        SCROLLINFO infoH;
        infoH.cbSize = sizeof (SCROLLINFO);
        infoH.fMask = SIF_PAGE;
        infoH.nPage = BAR_SIZE;
        m_hScrollBar.SetScrollInfo (&infoH);

        SCROLLINFO infoV;
        infoV.cbSize = sizeof (SCROLLINFO);
        infoV.fMask = SIF_PAGE;
        infoV.nPage = BAR_SIZE;
        m_vScrollBar.SetScrollInfo (&infoV);
        //滑塊大小

    }
    else
    {
        m_hScrollBar.SetScrollPos (0);
        m_hScrollBar.ShowWindow (SW_HIDE);
        m_vScrollBar.SetScrollPos (0);
        m_vScrollBar.ShowWindow (SW_HIDE);
    }
    RefreshSrcView ();
    return CDialogEx::OnMouseWheel (nFlags, zDelta, pt);
}
```